# Why the output is two string when I pass a one character string to a python function

Tags: python

I've created a function called swap for an experiment. The function is as below:

```
def swap(x):
    return x[-1:] + x[1:-1] + x[0:1]
```

When I try to pass a string "a", the output is "aa". I am not sure how's that happen. Thanks in advance if someone knows the reason.

Comment: In your function print `x[-1:]` and `x[0:1]` and see for yourself.

Comment: @lescurel - he swapps the first and last letter, you reverse the whole string. How is that helping?

Answer (score 3):

Your function returns a new string based on:

- The last letter of your string (`a`)
- everything *after* the first letter but *before* the last letter (empty in your case)
- and the first letter of your string (`a`)

So because your last letter *is* your first letter, you get them twice.

To swap them correctly, you'll have to test for string length:

```
def swap(x):
    if len(x) < 2:
        return x
    return x[-1] + x[1:-1] + x[0]
```

Now that you know that in the last line `x` is at least two characters long, you also don't need slicing for the first/last character and can use direct element access (`x[0]`/`x[-1]`).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is ok.

- `x[-1:]` will return the last character, becuase -1 starts from the end
- `x[0:1]` will return the first character from beginning
- `x[1:-1]` is nothing in this case because you don't have the second character

Btw for swap use `return x.reverse()` or `return x[::-1]`

Comment: The OP swapps the first and last letter, leaving the others in place `x.reverse()` and `x[::-1]` reverse the whole string...